# Mathematics "On the electrodynamics of moving bodies", where am I wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I have a question about the paper of Einstein; On the electrodynamics of moving bodies, below I post my question:
[image]

Comment: In the future, please use MathJax for equations here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this passage:

> ... where a is a function $\phi(v)$ at present unknown, and where for brevity it is assumed that at the origin of $k$, $\tau = 0$ when $t = 0$.

The first part says that $\phi(v)$ is (at present) unknown. The factor of 1/2 doesn't matter; $\phi(v)/2$ is just as unknown as $\phi(v)$.

The second part sets a boundary condition for determining the constant. In this case the condition is satisfied when the constant is zero.